# Limit of a string without recurence

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, string-theory

> Let the string $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ such that : $$\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}\cdots$$
>
> Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\cdot\sqrt{n}.$$

Hello.
I just found that problem and i have no ideea on solving it.
Actually we can see that $x_{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} = \frac{1}{n}$, but i don't really got nothing.
Somebody can help me? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Edited, i think is ok now?

Comment: maybe study $y_n=x_{n(n+1)/2}\sqrt{n(n+1)/2}$ and try to find lower/higher bound for other $x_n$ in function of $y_{n-1},y_n,y_{n+1}$.

Comment: I don't really understand ..

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint :}$

We have : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right)\left(\forall k\in\left[\!\left[0,n\right]\!\right]\right),\ x_{\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}+k}=\frac{1}{n+1} $$

A closed form for $ \left(x_{n}\right)_{n\geq 0} $ can be given as follows : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ x_{n}=\frac{1}{\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{1+8n}-1}{2}\right\rfloor +1} $$

Comment: Sorry but i really cant make it. Do you have a full solve? :/